# How to check null string type with go?

Tags: go

DB:

```
column: name
value: NULL
```

Get the record from DB with gorm, then

```
var name string
if name != nil {
  //
}
```

Got error:

```
invalid operation: name != nil (mismatched types string and nil)
```

Yes, nil is using for int type in go, but this case, the value in DB is `NULL` but not `""`, so it's necessary to check `null`, how to do?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a pointer to string to map NULL values from the database, but this will create cases where you cannot give values without creating a variable first.

```
var name *string
if name != nil {
  //
}

// but
name = "will not work"
```

Or you could use the `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`(or whatever driver you are using) and `database/sql` package implementations.
You can define your own types based on those if you want to add functionality:

```
// NullInt64 is an alias for sql.NullInt64 data type
type NullInt64 sql.NullInt64
// NullBool is an alias for sql.NullBool data type
type NullBool sql.NullBool
// NullFloat64 is an alias for sql.NullFloat64 data type
type NullFloat64 sql.NullFloat64
// NullString is an alias for sql.NullString data type
type NullString sql.NullString
// NullTime is an alias for mysql.NullTime data type
type NullTime mysql.NullTime
```

Answer (score 6):

You should pay your attention on sql types: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Just use variable with this type in your select statement:

```
var yourstr sql.NullString
db.Select("Select your string", &yourstr)
```

Then you could check if it is valid and if it is not you could assign any value you want:

```
if !yourstr.Valid{
  yourstr.String = ""
}
```

In gorm also is a function to select NullString:

```
yourstr := dbmap.SelectNullStr("Select your string")
```